# How to implement data visualization in ruby / ruby on rails using R?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, analytics

Disclaimer:  We're a collection of scientists that are just now getting into python/ruby.

Project summary:  We have analytics and usage data from social networking sites that we are using **R** and Highcharts (via lazy_high_chart gem) to present analytics to users through a website.  The user can interact with this data by specifying which and when they want to investigate a social media segment.  So the user defines the subject and the website responds with a slew of metrics.

Problem:  So far we have been using straight ruby to pull social networking data (one class), send it to the analytics engine (another class), and present it in plotted glory (final class).  However, this is all been proof of principle and console driven so it seems inefficient to push it to a site from this start.  Should we have started from the ground up with a rails framework and just built the site with all of these analytic engines built into the site?  Or...is it better to have this backend pipeline written in ruby that only interfaces with a rails framework trough yet another object?

A suggestion or pointer to a general document that hints on how to integrate backend data crunching with frontend rails would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is basically how to architecture the system, and this is somewhat hard answer since it usually depends on a lot of things: system requirements, application landscape, project planning, skills, etc.

But just looking at the two alternatives you mentioned, I think there's nothing wrong with creating a fresh Rails application, copying your prototype modules into the `lib/` directory and connecting things the standard way. You can use `rake tasks` to keep the console interface you already have. In the end, your setup looks quite similar to a standard web application. (Usually you have a database doing the "data crunching", in your case it is the R engine.)

I don't know any specific documentation about integration Rails with R, but some research about general system integration with Rails should give you a good starting point. (However, this would only be needed if you really want to build two independent systems.)

Comment: Good info, we're going to go ahead with the implementation you are outlining.  We'll have the console version as a backend to a rails frontend so we don't need to reimplement any code in the controllers or models of the rails app.  Also, this is something we would need to do anyway down the road since adding the twitter stream component to the whole project means we have to daemonize that part and run it along side the rails app.